# Как сложить расстояние и угол, чтобы получить вектор?

Tags: unity3d

Пытаюсь сложить расстояние и направление, чтобы получился вектор класса: "Vector3"
Как указать расстояния понял:`Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0, Distation, 0);`
А как указать угол например по Y?

Comment: Опишите реальную задачу

Comment: @MBo, У меня есть персонаж на определенном расстоянии от него и под рандомном углу относительно него, нужно сделать появление врага

Comment: Углы в пространстве существуют не сами по себе, а относительно каких-то направлений, осей или плоскостей.

Comment: @Mbo, Именно по этому, я сказал, что по оси Y

Comment: Нужно уточнить, что означает фраза " угол например по Y"?

Comment: @Mbo, По Y имею ввиду направление, которое например указывается в Rotation при создании объекта Y

Comment: Действие (персонаж, враг) происходит на плоскости или в 3d пространстве?

Comment: @MBo, в 3д, я уже сам понял, как это сделать через  синусы и косинусы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сгенерировать случайный единичный вектор, равномерно распределённый в пространстве, [можно сделать так](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html):

```
 Fi = random(0..1) * 2 * Pi

 u =  random(0..1) * 2 - 1
 su = Sqrt(1 - u^2)

 x = su * Cos(Fi)
 y = su * Sin(Fi)
 z = u
```

Чтобы сделать вектор длиной D, нужно все эти компоненты умножить на D

Comment: Тоже самое продумал